# Is there an open-source SQL database that has the concept of Oracle's "rowid" pseudo-column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rowid

I am aware that MySQL and PostgreSQL[1] do *not* have that concept, so I am interested in finding out of there is an open-source SQL database that does have the concept.

[1] It was later pointed out that PostgreSQL does have the rowid pseudo-column.

Comment: That seems like an awfully specific request to discount a whole database over. If you post the specific problem that you're trying to solve, someone might have an alternative solution.

Comment: Is your question really about ROWID, or about ROWNUM? The ROWNUM of a record can vary from query to query, but the ROWID does not.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to decide which database to use. This question was just inspired through a discussion I had with an Oracle friend.

To whether or not I mean ROWID or ROWNUM, my Oracle friend said ROWID, so I'll assume that I do not mean ROWNUM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PostgreSQL` does have this concept.

See [**here**](http://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/x4636) for a brief list of pseudocolumns in `PostgreSQL`, out of which `ctid` is of interest to you:

> `ctid (tuple identifier)`
>
> The identifier which describes the physical location of the tuple within the database. A pair of numbers are represented by the ctid: the block number, and tuple index within that block.

That is direct analog of `Oracle`'s `rowid`.

As for `MySQL`, physical location of a row is not available for the front end.

In `MyISAM`, `rowid` is just a file offset from the beginning, and that's what is stored in the index leaves.

In `InnoDB`, tables are `index organized` by design, that means they always have some kind of a primary key, and the indexes over an `InnoDB` table use that `PRIMARY KEY` as a row pointer.

This is also true for `Oracle`'s `index organized` tables, for which a `rowid` is not a physical pointer to a block in a datafile, but rather a such called `logical ROWID`, or `UROWID`

If you select a `ROWID` from an `INDEX ORGANIZED` table in `Oracle`, you will see that it has a different format (something like `*BAEBwPICwQL+`). This is in fact an encoded `PRIMARY KEY` value.

Note that if you have not defined any column as a `PRIMARY KEY`, `MySQL` will create a hidden surrogate `PRIMARY KEY` over which you will never have any control.

That's why you should always create some kind of a `PRIMARY KEY` in an `InnoDB` table: it's free, and you get control over the column.

Comment: It does?

I Googled for the answer, and found a forum post saying that PostgresQL does not have that concept.

Comment: Just try it if you don't believe me :)

Comment: By the way: by ROWID in Oracle you mean ROWID (physical pointer to a data block containing a record) or ROWNUM (incremental row number in a dataset returned from a SELECT query)? These are different things.

Answer (score 0):

if neither of them have done that, then no others do.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has an auto incremented "ROWID" column which you can access using ROWID, _ROWID, or OID. If you define an integer primary key than they will be aliased.

Comment: Not quite the same thing- the oracle feature is the row # of the results of a particular query.  So if you order by the id desc, the first result would still have rowid #1.

Comment: Ah I didn't understand that. Is there a use case for that (where you couldn't just do it by hand) ?

Comment: It's a way to get TOP(x) in a db that doesn't support that structure if you use a subquery:


SELECT * from ( 
  SELECT * myTable ORDER BY interestingField
) WHERE rowid > 101

Comment: Sorry - that query should be:  SELECT * from ( SELECT FROM * myTable ORDER BY interestingField ) WHERE rowid < 101

Comment: ROWID is NOT the same thing as ROWNUM. ROWNUM is the relative order of a result in a query. ROWID is a physical identifier that is static, unless records are physically relocated. It's almost always unique in the database.